# can i make a web service call in NETunnelProvider sub class ios

Tags: ios, networking, network-programming, networkextension

I am trying to make a webservice call to check status of DNS service in tunnel provider network extension? Is it allowed as per apples guideline?

Actually i am trying to impliment custom tunnel using network extesion framwork so that all traffice should go through this tunnel. now  if VPN is connected I have to check DNS service status in every 10 min using webservice call.

So my question is - Can i make a webservice call inside tunnel code (network extension) using dispatch time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the VPN tunnel thread to execute the web-services. You need to create separate thread to execute the web-services and receive callback.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Every time we use NSURLSession, another thread is created. BTW, I tried to use NSURLSession inside NETunnelProviderManager but requests are always cancelled. Perhaps it is related with what you said, but I'm sure it is using another thread. Any clue? Thanks a lot.